# Function to compute difference between 2 times

Tags: postgresql, functions, time, interval

I want to create a simple function in Postgres to find the difference between 2 `TIME` - not `TIMESTAMP`. As shown below, it accepts 4 parameters: hour, minute, second and expire (hour). In this example I have commented out seconds, just working on minutes.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION time_diff(hr INT, min INT, sec INT, exp_hr INT)
RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
DECLARE
    cur_time    TIME;
    expire_time TIME;

    diff_interval INTERVAL;
    diff INT = 0;
BEGIN
    cur_time    = CONCAT(hr,  ':',  min, ':', sec) AS TIME; -- cast hour, minutes and seconds to TIME
    expire_time = CONCAT(exp_hr, ':00:00') AS TIME;         -- cast expire hour to TIME

    -- MINUS operator for TIME returns interval 'HH:MI:SS;
    diff_interval = expire_time - cur_time;

    diff = DATE_PART('hour', diff_interval);

    diff = diff * 60 + DATE_PART('minute', diff_interval);

    --diff = diff * 60 + DATE_PART('second', diff_interval);

    RETURN diff;
END;
$$;
```

Example:
01:15:00 - 02:00:00 should give me 45 minutes, so I do the following and I get the correct answer.

```sql
select * from time_diff(1, 15, 0, 2);
```

However, if I do this: 23:15:00 - 01:00:00 - the should give me 105 minutes (60 + 45).

```sql
select * from time_diff(23, 15, 0, 1);
```

But the result I am getting is -1335. I am trying to work out where I have gone wrong here.

Also I am invoking `DATE_PART` functions, this seems to be a quite an expensive process in terms of CPU usage. Is there a better way of optimising this function. With the first example I am getting results in `0.007s` on 2018 i7 Mac mini. Although I do think this function is quick, but could it be better?

Comment: Please disclose your version of Postgres. Why integer numbers for input and output, instead of time, interval or timestamp values? Also, `exp_hr` is always ahead in time and never wraps around (> 24h)?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I am using Postgres 12.3, and  in this case `exp_hr` never exceeds 24. However, I can see in coding that you've wrapped this. Very handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `exp_hr` is always ahead in time, but never more than 24 hours.

I suggest to return an `interval` for simplicity. Then it works for hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds etc. alike.

Besides correct, this should be faster by orders of magnitude:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_time_diff(hr INT, min INT, sec INT, exp_hr INT)
  RETURNS interval
  LANGUAGE sql PARALLEL SAFE IMMUTABLE AS
$func$
SELECT CASE WHEN hr >= exp_hr       -- wrap around midnight
            THEN 24 + exp_hr - hr
            ELSE exp_hr - hr
            END * interval '1 hour'
                - interval '1 min' * min
                - interval '1 sec' * sec;
$func$;
```

Note that this returns 24h for input = output *exactly*. You might decide otherwise for the corner case.

Demo:

```
test=*> SELECT f_time_diff( 1, 15, 0, 2) AS example1
test-*>      , f_time_diff(23, 15, 0, 1) AS example2
test-*>      , f_time_diff( 1, 15, 0, 1) AS example3
test-*>      , f_time_diff( 1,  0, 0, 1) AS example4;
 example1 | example2 | example3 | example4 
----------+----------+----------+----------
 00:45:00 | 01:45:00 | 23:45:00 | 24:00:00
(1 row)
```

If you actually need the number of minutes as `integer`, (truncating seconds if any), extract the epoch and use integer division:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(epoch FROM f_time_diff(23,15,0,1))::int / 60 AS example2;  -- 105
```

(Or build that into the function.)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=50d51b9c65cfc0b22d3bf7d561d2d606)*

The most expensive part is the type conversion now. If you input `time` / `interval`, it gets much faster, yet. Or better yet: `timestamp` or `timestamptz`, then it gets trivial and you wouldn't need a function to begin with ...

Concatenating strings before casting to `time` (like you had it) is much more expensive, yet.

Comment: In your example 4, you have a time of 24:00:00 - I thought that this is impossible, except in the very particular case of a leap second being added? Again, my understanding was that a day started at 00:00:00 (zero-hundred hours) and could go up to 23:59:59.9999... recurring to ∞ , but that the time in a given day could never reach 24:00:00  - that's shown as 00:00:00 the **following** day?

Comment: @Vérace: Maybe you missed this bit: `Note that this returns 24h for input = output exactly.` It depends on undisclosed requirements how this should turn out. This is just the simplest way.

Comment: @Vérace: Oh, and the function returns an `interval`, not `time`. That may clear up any confusion.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thank you for the answer, this seems to be a better solution. And yes `interval` seems to be a better type with play with. Also it is quick.